# Can't connect to to HBase via phoenix with jdbc. Error NONODE, code 101

Tags: java, hbase, apache-phoenix

I try to connect to phoenix via jdbc with code

```
Connection r = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:serverName:8765/hbase");
```

Execution error

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2432)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2352)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2352)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:232)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:147)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:202)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at myfunction
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:392)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2378)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.getMetaReplicaNodes(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
    ... 45 more
```

Inside ZooKeeper I found another ignored exception:

```
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode
```

This exception produced by response error 101

```
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1472)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.getChildren(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:295)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.listChildrenNoWatch(ZKUtil.java:635)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.getMetaReplicaNodes(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:392)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:553)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:61)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1186)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1153)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:300)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:155)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:59)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:821)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:392)
 org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2378)
 org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2352)
 org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76)
 org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2352)
 org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:232)
 org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:147)
 org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:202)
 java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
 java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

Driver version 4.9.0-HBase-1.1

Version from Hbase shell 1.1.2.2.5.0.0-1245

PS: I'm able to connect to Hbase directly with HBase client API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mistake in connection string.

It should be `jdbc:phoneix[:zk_quorum][:zk_port][:zk_hbase_path]`

In my case `jdbc:phoenix:zookeperServerName:2181:/hbase-unsecure`